# download file with blob in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

im new to angular and i have to add a button to an app so when i click, it should start downloading a file already recorded.

i have this code

```
var _RecordStopCallback = function(blob){
            if (!blob && blob.length==0){
                $scope.isRecorded = false;
                return;
            }
            $scope.recordObj.recordedData = blob;
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              var el = $("#downloads").html("");
              var hf = $("<a></a>");
              hf.attr({
                  src:url,
                  href:url,
                  download:$scope.recordFilename
              }).html($scope.recordFilename);
              hf.appendTo(el);
              $scope.isStoping = false;
            $scope.recordStatus = false;
            $scope.isRecorded = true;
            $scope.recordStatusText = "Start";
            $scope.streamError = "";
            _changeStatusText();
            $scope.$apply();
            $scope.saveProcess();
```

and in the HTML file this:

```
<div ng-show="isRecorded" class="color-info"> Recorded File : <span id='downloads'></span> 
<button ng-click="{{recordFilename}}" class="btn-circle btn-circle-default">
<i class="zmdi zmdi-download"></i></button>
```

this line:

```
<span id='downloads'></span>
```

displays the recoded filename and makes it as a link so when you click on it you can directly donwload it, but i dont know how to make the button do the same thing?

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may register a callback for the button getting clicked and there you can create the same link you showed in your question, style it as hidden, insert it into the DOM and call `.click()` on it.
Inserting into DOM is required as some browsers will not start the download otherwise.

Comment: Never used AngularJS (only Angular 2+) and cannot write extensive code samples from my mobile phone. Probably you can add a function `download` to `$scope`. There just create your `a` element, call `.css('display', 'none')` on it, append it to your `#downloads` element and then call `.click()` on it. Bind your `download` function to the button by writing `download()` instead of `{{recordFilename}}`. The latter may be written as the button's content, next to the `i` element. Try it and show us your progress if it doesn't work.